# How to delete the post posted as guest into a stackexchange site?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question as a guest and now I have to delete the post since it contains some research data. Since I post it as a guest I can not delete it. I can confirm my email address to show that I am the person who asked that question.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Merge the accounts, then the post will be yours. Then edit out the sensitive content from the post. Then flag the post and ask the mod - politely - for a *redact*. Mods can edit also the previous versions of posts (in the case of ordinary mortals, all their previous versions remain visible). It is not something what the mods do very happily, so show them a strong reason (i.e. accidental data leak is enough strong).

Comment: In many cases, you can't delete your own post! Even if you can, the post remains still readable for many people! So a deletion won't help! The only way to really eliminate the sensitive data, if you ask the mods for a redact!